# Show the nearest route for a branch in angularjs/google maps

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps

I have created a map to show some branches to a shop with angularjs.i have created a array of branches and i have shown them in my map.

```
$scope.locations = {
          BranchAndAtms: [
          {
          id: "1",
          outlet: "Piliyandala",
          address: "Piliyandala Post Office Piliyandala",
          lat: "6.802107",
          lon: "79.921749",
          isAtm: "yes",
          status: "yes",
          map: map,
          tel: "0111231231"
          },
          {
          id: "2",
          outlet: "Monaragala",
          address: "No.100, New Bus Stand , Monaragala.",
          lat: "6.877530",
          lon: "79.907055",
          isAtm: "yes",
          status: "yes",
          map: map,
          tel: "0111231231"
          },
    ]
}
```

like this.and also i can get my current location using

```
var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(c.latitude, c.longitude);
```

So far i can show the route to a hard coded branch location. But i want to know how i can get the latitudes and longitudes from my array and compare it with my current location and show the route. How i can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to do some research on Angular JS concepts in order to have  a modular code and also the terminologies associated with that. You need to write the code where you have the arrays of locations in something called as **Controller**. The main purpose of controller is to  holds initial variables, that are to be passed to our directive. Rest of the code goes into something called as **Directive**.  Controller holds initial variables, that are to be passed to our directive.

I would recommend you going through this [tutorial](http://ericpanorel.net/2013/08/11/angularjs-and-google-maps/) for complete step by step implementation.